# What would a surgeon write about a non-complicated scar in a post-surgery inspection report?

Tags: terminology

I have a short post-surgery inspection report in Russian:

> Осмотр после операции. Рубец спокойный.

Verbatim translation:

> Post-surgery examination. The scar is **calm**.

This **calm** denotes that the scar is not inflamed and is healing in a "calm", normal fashion. I wonder what would an English-speaking doctor write there. "Scar uncomplicated"?

The examination was performed 2 months post-surgery.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a translation service

Comment: @GrahamChiu - there's a huge difference between a translation request and a terminology request.

Comment: https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I think it might be worth checking if this would be on-topic on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/) or [RU](https://russian.stackexchange.com/)